# why performanceCounter shows me more than 100 %

Tags: c#, performancecounter

#### Scenario:

I have tried for the first time `performanceCounter` and it shows me a nonsense result.

this is the code i used:
[image]

this is the setup of the `performanceCounter` properties
[image]

this is the result

[image]

you can see that the proc is 1442%,  this  is impossible.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Post code as text.

Comment: your conversion is wrong, first why you convert to int while the value is float, and second the string format syntax is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `%` format specifier which, to quote the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings):

> Multiplies a number by 100 and inserts a localized percentage symbol in the result string.

If the number is already a percentage and you just want to show the % symbol after it, move the symbol out of the format specifier, like so:

```
string.Format("{0}%", fcpu);
```

As suggested in the comments, using the `F1` or `D1` format specifiers is probably more appropriate in this case ([documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings))

Comment: what exactly can I do bro ?

Comment: @bilalBOUASRIA Try `F1` instead of `%`.

Comment: excellent I did "{0:0}%"  instead of this "{0:0%}"